# Operation Timed out while counting the number of rows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've got 3 nodes in 2 datacenters. On each node I'm using the same cqlshrc file having just the following lines:

```
[connection] 
request_timeout = 3600
```

Replication strategy is as follows :

```
class:NetworkTopologyStrategy, 'dc1' :2, 'dc2':1
```

I've inserted more than 100 000 rows in the database. However when I execute 
`select count(*) from table`,  I get "operation timed out" in 2 of the 3 nodes.  i.e. the query is successful in one node.

Why is the query unsuccessful in 2 out of 3 nodes despite each having same cqlshrc file?

- OS: RHEL 6
- Cassandra:3.0.14

Comment: Did you check the log files for the nodes that throw timeout?

Comment: I can see only one warning :"Aggregation query used without partition key" in the logs. Apart from this, I couldn't understand anything else

Comment: How is your data distributed? On which nodes does it fail? Are they on the same dc?

Comment: I've got total 3 nodes and 2 datacentres. The node on which the command is successful(Node 1) is in dc 1 along with another node(Node 2). Node 3 is in dc 2. On both node 2 and node 3, the command is unsuccessful. Network Topology Strategy with replication in dc1: 2 and dc2: 1

Answer (score 4):

**In cassandra `count(*)` is a very costly operation, need to scan all the row from all the node just to give you the count and can generate timeout exception.**

So Instead of using `count(*)` maintain a counter table for example :

```
CREATE TABLE page_view_counts (
    counter_value counter,
    url_name varchar,
    page_name varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (url_name, page_name)
);
```

Whenever a new row inserted into base table increment the count plus one

```
UPDATE page_view_counts
   SET counter_value = counter_value + 1
   WHERE url_name = 'stackoverflow.com' AND page_name = 'questions';
```

Now to get the count just try like below

```
SELECT * FROM page_view_counts 
   WHERE url_name = 'stackoverflow.com' AND page_name = 'questions';
```

Comment: But I didn't understand why the query works perfectly fine each time on one of the 3 nodes and fails in the other two despite each having same cqlshrc file. It seems like on the other 2 nodes there is no effect of the configuration given in the cqlshrc file.